# Numpy fusing multiply and add to avoid wasting memory

Tags: python, numpy, memory, multiplication

Is it possible to multiply two ndarray A, and B and add the result to C, without creating a large intermediate array for A times B?

Numpy has the out keyword parameter for the case of C = A times B:

```
numpy.multiply(A, B, out=C)
```

How about the case of C += A times B?

Comment: Then use `numpy.add(... out = C)`? No extra array created that way.

Comment: @Divakar that still creates an intermediate for A times B

Comment: Are you worried about memory or performance or both? In the [`comments`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200278/numpy-fusing-multiply-and-add#comment77367878_45200335) and question being tagged as `memory` suggests its `memory` that you are focussing on. If that's the case, `numpy.add` uses no extra memory, as mentioned earlier as well.

Comment: Are you hitting memory errors?  Otherwise I question whether it's worth your time to micromanage `numpy's` use of memory.  If it's speed you are worried about, try several options on realistic arrays and see it they make any difference.

Comment: Writing and commenting on SO takes time. Yes, it is out of memory error. I really did a calculation on #elements multiplied by 1e-9 and 4 to get memory used in Gb, and know the machine only has 8Gb memory... It sucks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Numpy only supports operations one at a time. With that said, there are several workarounds.

#### In place operations

The most simple solution is to use in-place operations via `+=` and `*=`

```
import numpy as np

n = 100
b = 5.0

x = np.random.rand(n)
y = np.random.rand(n)

z = b * x
z += y
```

#### BLAS

You can access the underlying [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) programs and apply them manually. Sadly, there is no multiply add instruction, but there is the "AXPY" instruction, which performs

```
y <- a * x + y
```

This can be called via:

```
import scipy

axpy = scipy.linalg.blas.get_blas_funcs('axpy', arrays=(x, y))
axpy(x, y, n, b)
```

#### Numexpr

Another option is to use some package like [`numexpr`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numexpr) which allows you to compile expressions:

```
import numexpr

z = numexpr.evaluate('b * x + y')
```

#### Theano

Recently several machine-learning packages have started supporting compiled expressions, one such package is theano. You could do something like:

```
import theano

x = theano.tensor.vector()         # declare variable
y = theano.tensor.vector()         # declare variable

out = b * x + y                    # build symbolic expression
f = theano.function([x, y], out)   # compile function

z = f(x, y)
```

Comment: linalg is nice, but not for numpy array with dimension > 2. Will try numexpr. Hope that works.

Comment: Please report back with status! Added some other options as well

Comment: i guess numpy could have an add_to keyword. But I haven't read the code base and don't know if adding that feature is difficult.

Comment: Numpy does not have a add-to keyword sadly

Comment: it works. `import numpy as np; import numexpr as ne; a = np.ones(int(1.9e9),dtype=np.int32).reshape((2,4,5,-1)); print(ne.evaluate("a*a+a",out=a))` didn't use swap.

Comment: Does += actually solve the problem? I believe it still creates a temporary result on the RHS of the operation.

Comment: It does, but it helps in related cases. Numexpr style stuff is the only full solution here.

Answer (score 7):

I compared different variants and found that you're not going wrong with SciPy's BLAS interface

```py
scipy.linalg.blas.daxpy(x, y, len(x), a)
```

[image]

---

Code to reproduce the plot:

```py
import numexpr
import numpy as np
import perfplot
import scipy.linalg
import theano

a = 1.36

# theano preps
x = theano.tensor.vector()
y = theano.tensor.vector()
out = a * x + y
f = theano.function([x, y], out)


def setup(n):
    x = np.random.rand(n)
    y = np.random.rand(n)
    return x, y


def manual_axpy(data):
    x, y = data
    return a * x + y


def manual_axpy_inplace(data):
    x, y = data
    out = a * x
    out += y
    return out


def scipy_axpy(data):
    x, y = data
    n = len(x)
    axpy = scipy.linalg.blas.get_blas_funcs("axpy", arrays=(x, y))
    axpy(x, y, n, a)
    return y


def scipy_daxpy(data):
    x, y = data
    return scipy.linalg.blas.daxpy(x, y, len(x), a)


def numpexpr_evaluate(data):
    x, y = data
    return numexpr.evaluate("a * x + y")


def theano_function(data):
    x, y = data
    return f(x, y)


b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=setup,
    kernels=[
        manual_axpy,
        manual_axpy_inplace,
        scipy_axpy,
        scipy_daxpy,
        numpexpr_evaluate,
        theano_function,
    ],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(24)],
    equality_check=None,
    xlabel="len(x), len(y)",
)
# b.save("out.png")
b.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand, NumPy array operations can only be done one at a time, but by putting it inside of a function you can ensure it is not in memory, as the commenter suggested.

Comment: erh. I guess we are talking about `numpy.add(A*B, out=C)`. That needs memory to hold A times B, and memory to hold the original value of C. That add function alone doesn't do multiplication. A times B will be evaluated by python interpreter first, and put into an intermediate array. After that, the intermediate is added to C.

Comment: Yes, but then A times B would no longer be in memory.

Comment: Well. When the intermediate exists, we need memory. If there isn't enough memory for both C and the intermediate at that point, the program will get out of memory error. And not enough memory is the problem.

Comment: You have a case where you cannot hold the multiple of two matrices, but you can hold those two added to a third matrix with the same size? Doesn't seem probable to me.

Comment: Yes. Outer product of two 3 element vector gives a 9 element array. A and B are much smaller than C, but A*B and C have same size. I have enough memory to hold A, B, and C, but not enough to hold A, B, C, and the intermediate.

Comment: we shouldn't need that intermediate, but if numpy creates that intermediate first before adding the whole intermeddiate array to C. Well, that is a waste of memory.

Comment: is there a way to do this operation mathematically without an intermediate? Then you can do the same thing.

Comment: the point of using a library is not to do everything yourself. doing everything yourself is the last resort.