# NumPy add output from np.dot or np.multiply to existing array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In `NumPy`, it's possible to specify an argument to `np.dot` and `np.multiply` called `out`, so that they won't create a new array when returning the result. However, in my use case, I need to compute the following:

1. `c = c + np.dot(a, b) # where a and b are matrices of shape n x m, and m x p`
2. `c = c + np.multiply(a, b) # where a and b are matrices of equal shape n x m`

Is there a way to do this without creating a new array each time? For example, something like this:

1. `np.dot(a, b, add_to=c)`
2. `np.multiply(a, b, add_to=c)`

Comment: May be mdot http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/MultiDot.html?

Comment: @MishaVacic That looks like a shortcut to multiply several matrices. I need a way to add the result of either `dot` or `multiply` to some other array without creating a new array.

Comment: Use a single temp array and `+=`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Is there no way to do it without a temp array?

Comment: @michaelsnowden. I can't imagine one unless you rewrite `dot` yourself. However, if you show me how you get `c`, it may be possible to compute `c` into the same buffer that dot uses, making it unnecessary to allocate an *additional* temp.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Initially `c` is zero'd out, then 1 and 2 are applied over and over from different places in the code. I guess I could have a single temp like you said and do `np.dot(a, b, out=temp); c += temp` and `np.multiply(a, b, out=temp); c+= temp`

Comment: I was hoping for something simpler. If `c` was just a sum or product of a simple thing, you could do the multiplication using `c` as the output, then add in whatever you needed.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yeah, unfortunately I can't do that

Comment: Fortunately though, @divakar has solved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like a perfect setup to leverage blas wrappers supported by [`scipy.linalg.blas`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/linalg.blas.html) that support matrix-multplications with accumulation into an existing array.

So, for the first `dot` problem, we could simply use their `sgemm (single-precision)/dgemm (double-precision)`, like so -

```
from scipy.linalg.blas import dgemm, sgemm

dgemm(alpha=1.0, a=a, b=b, c=c, beta=1.0)
```

The format being `C = alpha*(a x b) + beta*C`.

`*` : elementwise multiplication

`x` : matrix multiplication

Sample run -

1) Setup inputs :

```
In [549]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(3,4))
     ...: b = np.random.randint(0,9,(4,5))
     ...: c = np.random.randint(0,9,(3,5))
     ...: 

In [550]: c
Out[550]: 
array([[2, 4, 7, 6, 1],
       [8, 7, 2, 1, 7],
       [4, 3, 5, 4, 4]])
```

2) Make a copy of the output array for later testing :

```
In [551]: c_copy1 = c.copy()
```

3) Use `np.dot` on original output array :

```
In [552]: c = c + np.dot(a, b)

In [553]: c
Out[553]: 
array([[88, 94, 75, 66, 93],
       [55, 51, 55, 38, 65],
       [61, 51, 25, 45, 68]])
```

3) Use `dgemm` on copy -

```
In [554]: dgemm(alpha=1.0, a=a, b=b, c=c_copy1, beta=1.0)
Out[554]: 
array([[ 88.,  94.,  75.,  66.,  93.],
       [ 55.,  51.,  55.,  38.,  65.],
       [ 61.,  51.,  25.,  45.,  68.]])
```

Note that if you are doing this in iterations, we need to assign it back into the output array.

---

For the second problem, similarly we can use `saxpy/daxpy` from the same module. This has been covered with few other alternatives in [`this other post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45200499/).

Comment: Are you sure SAXPY will work for the multiply operation? SAXPY requires A to be a scalar, not a vector for element-wise multiplication.

Comment: @michaelsnowden Guess we need a closer look there.