# Turning a For loop with an If statement into Numpy form Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, function, numpy

How could I write a function in numpy where `Set` and `Numbers` are in relation to each other and if the index of numbers is equivalent to `L` in `Set` the `Numbers` values are going to be multiplied by `Lval` otherwise `Numbers` are going to be multiplied by `Uval`. I am essentially trying to modify the vanilla python code to numpy version.

```
Set = np.array(['U' 'L' 'U' 'U' 'L' 'U' 'L' 'L' 'U' 'L' 'U' 'L' 'L' 'L' 'L'])
Numbers = np.array([ 52599  52599  53598 336368 336875 337466 338292 356587 357474 357763 358491 358659 359041 360179 360286])
Lval = 30
Uval = 10
```

Vanilla Python Version

```
Val = []
for x in Set:
   if Set[x] == 'U':
       calc = Numbers[x] * Uval
       Val.append(calc)
   else:
       calc = Numbers[x] * Uval
       Val.append(calc)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this code will raise a syntax error.

Comment: Please **always** provide a [mcve]. Don't be lazy

Comment: Lookup `numpy.where` .

Comment: BTW your Python version is wrong. `x` is a string, it would throw a type error with `Set[x]` and `Numbers[x]`, iterating over a container gives you the *elements* of the container, not the indices...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

#### Edit to bring the multiplication out so as to only do it once as suggested by @fountainhead  in the comments

```
Numbers * np.where(Set == 'U', Uval, Lval)
```

> ```
> numpy.where(condition[, x, y])
> ```
>
> Return elements chosen from x or y depending on condition

So, for example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> Set = np.array(['U', 'L', 'U', 'U', 'L', 'U', 'L', 'L', 'U', 'L', 'U', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'])
>>> Numbers = np.array([ 52599,  52599,  53598, 336368, 336875, 337466, 338292, 356587, 357474, 357763, 358491, 358659, 359041, 360179, 360286])
>>> Lval = 30
>>> Uval = 10
>>> Numbers * np.where(Set == 'U', Uval, Lval)
array([  525990,  1577970,   535980,  3363680, 10106250,  3374660,
       10148760, 10697610,  3574740, 10732890,  3584910, 10759770,
       10771230, 10805370, 10808580])
```

One caveat, you end up using a lot of extra space, since you have to create the array `Set == 'U'`, to pass it to the `condition` parameter `numpy.where`, and an intermediate array of Uval and Lvals. (and potentially other arrays to pass as the `x` and `y` parameters of `numpy.where`).

Despite all the unnecessary intermediates, it is still quite fast:

```
>>> Numbers = np.repeat(Numbers, 1000)
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("Numbers * np.where(Set == 'U', Uval, Lval)", "from __main__ import np, Set, Numbers, Lval, Uval", number=10000)
1.067108618999555
```

The equivalent Python:

```
>>> setlist = Set.tolist()
>>> numberlist = Numbers.tolist()
>>> timeit.timeit("[n*Uval if s =='U' else n*Lval for s, n in zip(setlist, numberlist)]", "from __main__ import setlist, numberlist, Lval, Uval", number=10000)
10.844363432000023
```

Comment: For memory usage there are some suggestions in [python - Numpy fusing multiply and add to avoid wasting memory - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200278/numpy-fusing-multiply-and-add-to-avoid-wasting-memory).

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler and more efficient to do `Numbers * np.where(Set == 'L', Lval, Uval)`  , and let broadcasting take care of everything ? There'd be fewer multiplications.

Comment: @fountainhead yes, absolutely

Comment: @fountainhead interestingly, I didn't a significant speed increase, but it is more elegant nonetheless

Comment: Hello there thanks for the code I have another issue relating to the `np.where` function. If you could take a look at this issue I would appreciate it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65999759/using-multiple-functions-with-correlated-arrays-numpy-python?noredirect=1#comment116692000_65999759